# Why wordpress plugins not working using PHP 8?

Tags: wordpress, svg, sitemap, php-8

I have updated the PHP version from 7.4 to 8.0 and some plugins are not working and showing errors like below

Error:
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: That is a question you should ask the creator of that plugin. There are hopefully updates available as PHP 7.4 has reached eol.

Answer (score -1):

Please check PHP version requirements of the plugin. So you will get your answer why it is not working.